# Is it true that Java implicitly defines references to the objects used in classes?

Tags: java, reference

After reading the books, surfing the nets regarding the type of references in Java, I still have some doubts (or I may have interpreted the concept wrong).
It would be a great help for me if anyone clear my doubts.

Let me take an example of a class containing class variables, instance variables and local variables.

```
public class Test {
  public static ArrayList<String> listCommon = new ArrayList<String>();
  private HashMap<String, String> mapInstance;

  public Test() {
    mapInstance = new HashMap<String, String>();
  }

  public void doSomething(String key) {
    ArrayList<String> local = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(key != null){
      local.add(mapInstance.get(key));
    }

    System.out.println("Value is added in instance Map: ", mapInstance.get(key));
  }
}
```

My Question are;
1. are `listCommon` (static variable) and `mapInstance` (instance variable) Strong reference towards Garbage Collector?
2. Is variable `local` (defined and used in method) a Weak reference?
3. How the Phantom reference and Soft reference came in picture?
4. OR above 3 concepts are invalid; means that Java defines the references only if you explicitly used the type defined in java.lang.ref package?

Any help would be great for me.

Comment: `local` is a `ArrayList<String>` and `mapInstance.get(key)` returns a `String`... this does not compile. Perhaps you mean `local.add(mapInstance.get(key));` ?

Comment: @Naved: everything is strong reference unless you explicitly used the type defined in java.lang.ref package.

Comment: is it so? so that means only Strong reference is defined implicitly.

Comment: Yep... everything's strong referenced by default, which will prevent the referenced object being garbage collected. You need EXPLICITLY use "weak" references (et al) if you want the object to eligble for collection even though you're still holding references to it. When you think anbout it... anything else would be madness, regardless of scope, yeah?

Comment: @MarkBooth, My intention of asking the question was not only to find out the answer to my doubts but also to listen the concepts from the experts. The answer had provided me all the details which I missed to search on the internet and hence I selected it as my answer.

Comment: @MarkBooth, Yes I missed that basic requirement of the site. I will change my acceptance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1. are listCommon (static variable) and mapInstance (instance variable) Strong reference towards Garbage Collector?

They are strong references, yes.

> 1. Is variable local (defined and used in method) a Weak reference?

No, it is a local variable, so it is a variable, so it is still a strong reference.

> 1. How the Phantom reference and Soft reference came in picture?

If you use them. If you don't use them you don't need to worry about them. They are for writing various kinds of caches really.

> 1. OR above 3 concepts are invalid; means that Java defines the references only if you explicitly used the type defined in
>      java.lang.ref package?

Reference *variables* are always strong. The other kinds only arise when you use them explicitly.

Comment: +1 for the answer, although for the sake of completeness I feel "strong reference" is a better term to use than "local strong reference". It is a local variable but there isn't any such thing as "local strong reference" AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

Read [this](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references) blog post about variable references.

** **Update** **

An atomic reference is an object referenced in such a way that it is accessed atomically; meaning that there are no race condition accessing it. For example:

```
class RaceTest {
   static private int count = 0;
   static public void main(String...args) {
      Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
                 count++;
             }
      });
      Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
                 count--;
             }
         }
      });

      t1.start();
      t2.start();

      t1.join();
      t2.join();

      System.out.println("Final count (should be 0) = " + count);
   }
}
```

Will spawn two threads that 1) will increment `count` and 2) will decrement it. Now, both threads will run in parallel and the program will wait until both terminate (at the `join` point). A common idea would be that since both threads have the same loop (will loop the same amount of time), each will "cancel" each other's operation and thus `count` should be 0, but this is not the case. Why? Because while, for example, `t1` may want to increase the variable, such operation is not atomic, but is more in the order of : `get`, `inc`, `set`. So there may be cases that, even before the second operation `inc` is made, `t2` would have accessed the variable and `dec` the variable, thus `t1` would have had actually `+2` the variable. And vice versa in an indefinite manner. (Each run of the code would produce a different value.)

Now, replacing `int` by `AtomicInteger` and using `incrementAndGet()` or `decrementAndGet()` will solve the issue by rendering the `get`, `inc`, `set` into a single operation, and eliminating the race condition in the code.

Comment: what is atomic reference then?

Comment: Although all answers are correct, but I am accepting this because of the valuable contents provided in the link.

Comment: @Mark, just because I used a link instead of writing an exhaustive answer, repeating what's in the link, this does not justify a downvote. And the link does provide the answer to his question.

Comment: Although the link and other stuffs helped me to explore my knowledge, I accepted another answer as per the FAQ written for this site.

Answer (score 3):

Answer to questions:

1. Yes, they are strong reference. Weak Reference are defined using [Weak reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) Object.
2. No, reason as 1).
3. [Phantom Reference](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) doesn't apply in your example. By default, all instances are strong reference.
4. Yes, you specify weak/phantom reference using the `java.lang.ref` package. By default, strong reference is used.

Note: A wikipedia explaination of [Weak Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference#Java_Example) might be useful.